# Confused about compiling a DLL file in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to make a DLL but I don't understand how to compile my code into a DLL.   I have my class library. What do I do when I'm ready to compile it?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you mean by "dll". If what you mean is that you want *a file that ends with .dll and can be used by more than one .NET project*, then just build the project. If you actually want a true .dll that a native compiler could link against, then .NET cannot create those.

Answer (score 2):

You build it. :-)

It should be in your /bin directory after building.

Answer (score 0):

All you normally have to do to create a .dll is to build the solution. Visual Studio will create the file for you in the /bin directory of the file.

If you wish to use the VS command line to make a .dll, consult this walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z(v=vs.100).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have several possible ways to build your solution

- You can use csc.exe (read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx))
- You can merely use your IDE. (Press F5 on VS)
- You can use MSBuild (read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx))
- You can use NAnt for building (read [here](http://nant.sourceforge.net/))

Answer (score 0):

on `SolutionExplorer`, right click on your project and click `Build` or `Rebuild`.

to using it:

1- Click `Project`, and then `Add Reference`.

2- Click the `Browse` tab and locate the DLL you want to add a reference to. (May be in `/bin` directory of project)

*Apparently using Browse is bad form if the DLL you want to use is in the same project. Instead, right-click the `Project` and then click `Add Reference`, then select the appropriate class from the Project tab.*

3- Click `OK`.

for ore information see: [How to Create a Class Library in C# .NET](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s16p1.html)